# Begin with remote deployment for SharePoint

Tags: deployment

I want to know how to begin remote deployment for SharePoint, that instead of doing deployment for files and pages using xml, now we can do them in JavaScript. Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newly-suggested "remote provisioning" options use CSOM/JSOM/REST, et.al.

I learned about this in the excellent MVA course here:

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/transform-sharepoint-customizations-to-sharepoint-app-model